# Can't log in to existing Clearance accounts after upgrading from Rails 2.3 to 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-2, clearance

Working on upgrading an old Rails 2.3 application to use Rails 4. Everything is running just fine so far, except that after upgrading Clearance to the latest stable version I am no longer able to log in to existing user accounts. There's no error, other than incorrect email or password. I can also create new accounts and log in to them just fine, but the existing ones are unaccessible and I'd like to not have to reset hundreds of passwords for the users if at all possible.

I know that Clearance started using BCrypt instead of SHA1 in the versions used after Rails 2.3, so I have set the `config.password_strategy = Clearance::PasswordStrategies::SHA1` in my `/config/initializers/clearance.rb` in order to have it use the same encryption that the accounts were created with. But this hasn't solved the problem.

Any suggestions? I feel like some other sort of "secret" key was set somewhere in the old application that I need to bring over to the new application in order for the login decryption to work, but I don't know much about that kind of thing yet.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read the upgrade guide? At the bottom it says you need to run a migration to downcase email addresses. That might be the problem: https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance/wiki/upgrading-clearance

Comment: @Sharagoz Thank you, I had not even found that page before, despite having read the README. I just ran the downcase migration but it didn't solve the problem quite yet. I will read through the rest of it and make sure I've complied with everything else. Thank you for pointing me in that direction! If there's anything else you can think of I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: I dont use clearence myself so I cant help you further unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

So I've got it working, and while I don't quite understand specifically how this fixes the problem, I wanted to share in case this ever helps someone else.

In `/config/initializers/clearance.rb` I switched from `config.password_strategy = Clearance::PasswordStrategies::SHA1` to `config.password_strategy = Clearance::PasswordStrategies::BCryptMigrationFromSHA1`.

I used `Clearance::Token.new` from the Rails console to generate a new `remember_token` and then I updated the database by hand so that the account I needed had this `remember_token`.

The combination of those two things allowed me to access old existing user account that I couldn't before. I plan on writing a quick script that will backfill all the other existing accounts with a generated `remember_token`. There were multiple discussions on the Clearance GitHub about backfilling these user remember_tokens but running the initialization script didn't do that when I installed the new Clearance.

If anyone wants to expand on this and explain exactly why it works, please do.